# Where do I place my own code whilst using Vagrant+Chef+Wordpress (VCCW) repository cloned from GitHub?

Tags: wordpress, git, vagrant, chef-infra

I ran across the [VCCW project](http://vccw.cc/) and despite my unfamiliarity with Vagrant and Chef, decided to give a try. I followed their instructions and obtained the VCCW project itself by installing the GitHub Windows program and cloning the VCCW GitHub master repository. I should also mention that I have very little experience with Git.

Anyway, now I have VCCW Wordpress running on my machine, but I've no clue what to do from here. I wanted to set up a better and more formal Wordpress development environment so I could write my plugin and modify a theme, but I don't know where I should do that. I know where the actual Wordpress installation resides on my file system, so I suppose it would be easy to work from there, but I don't know how (if at all) that interplays with the Vagrant workflow - ie, when it comes time to use Vagrant to deploy my site, will my changes to the "www" folder (which was created by `vagrant up`) be captured? Somehow I doubt this. Just looking for any help as to how all these fancy new tools work with each other and what a humble PHP developer like myself should do to get started.

Edit: One more question: which IDE, if any, can I use in conjunction with this arrangement? Create a new project from existing sources, and let it pollute my deployment folder with project files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/miya0001/vccw/blob/master/Vagrantfile.sample#L70), it looks like you should look in `./www/wordpress` after provisioning.

Comment: Ok - what about when it comes time to deploy it to where it will be hosted?

Comment: This has nothing to do with production deploys. VCCW is a local development tool from the looks of it. If you want a production deployment option, you can look over the Chef cookbooks they use and at more production-y Chef options.

Answer (score 0):

VCCW includes deployment tool `WordMove`.

You can deploy WordPress into your server from vccw if you set `Movefile`.
`Movefile` will be created automatically after provisioning, so you should add your server configuration in `Movefile`.

- http://vccw.cc/#h2-10
- https://github.com/welaika/wordmove